# document.getElementById variable change value of class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code:

```
table_div = document.getElementById('exporttbl');
```

Now I need to use jquery to change all values of th and td with specific class? (but just in variable table_div. And not on the page.)

Example:
I need to put this

```
<th class="one">AAA<th><td class="one">BBB<td>
```

into this

```
<th class="one">RRR<th><td class="one">RRR<td>
```

In the next step I am using

```
var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

so I would like to be able to use it.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Since your using jQuery you can do a `.find(".one")` on the element with the id `exporttbl` and change the text like so:

```
$("#exporttbl").find(".one").text("AAA");
```

Also note you need to close your `<th>` and `<hr>` elements. This would work for a table that looks like so:

```
<table id="exporttbl">
    <th class="one">AAA</th><td class="one">BBB</td>
    <th class="one">CCC</th><td class="one">DDD</td>
</table>
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/sr78v5vc/).

For more information see jQuery documentation - https://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

I think that some of the confusion here is that you are using

```
   table_div = document.getElementById('exporttbl');
```

which is pure javascript but then you say that you want to use jQuery.

"Now I need to use jquery to change all values of th and td with specific class? (but just in variable table_div. And not on the page.)"

This will return the jQuery object for that table.

```
    $('#exporttbl')
```

For all of the th, just add a find:

```
    $('#exporttbl').find('th.one')
```

and for all of the td:

```
    $('#exporttbl').find('td.one')
```

These will find all of the th/td with class = 'one' inside of the table with id = 'exporttbl'.  Then you can do whatever you want with them.  It sounds like you want to change the text so the following would work:

```
    $('#exporttbl').find('th.one').text('RRR');
    $('#exporttbl').find('td.one').text('RRR');
```

You could use

```
    $("#exporttbl").find(".one").text("AAA");
```

as suggested but that will find *all* items with class = "one" inside of the table.  That's fine as long as the th/td you want are the only items with that class.  If there is anything else with that class then you'll need to be more specific, as I was.

Also, using a selector like 'th.one' is typically faster than just '.one' which may or may not be an issue depending on the size of the application.